# Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)

Tags: biblatex, numbering

How can I set biblatex to insert "1. " before first bibliography item and so on? The bibliography is sorted by author and the numbers are not meant to be used anywhere else.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear-ibid,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}`.

Comment: It works (only comsetical differences, [1] instead of 1.). Is bibstyle=numeric different form bibstyle=standard in any other way too?

Comment: It sorts by (author) name - title - year (which may be corrected with `sorting=nyt`, see edited comment) and doesn't display the year immediately after the author.

Answer (score 14):

Biblatex manual section 3.5.7 actually has a solution for this, I must have missed it the previous time. Changed `\list` to `\enumerate`:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\enumerate
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endenumerate}
  {\item}
```

Comment: Note that the `\setlength`s do nothing in this example. Unlike `\list` from the example from the `biblatex` documentation (due to some additions it is now in §3.7.7) `\enumerate` does not take two mandatory arguments. That means that the `\setlength`s are executed in an explicit group and their effect vanishes immediately. Hence the code is equivalent to `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}{\enumerate}{\endenumerate}{\item}`

Comment: Thanks a ton! you saved me .... I was trying to do this for an hour  Thankssss again 