# Adding numbers to Author Year citations in list of references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am new to latex so please excuse any beginner errors..

I am using lyx to write a paper (article class) and i am using bibtex to generate my bibliography (kluwer style). My citations need to be referred to in text as Author (Year) or (Author, Year) and in my list of references as Author (Year) title etc..which I have managed to do.

but...i need to number the citations in the list of references. is there any way to change a list of references to an itemised list?

thanks!

Comment: uhm... I don't quite understand what you mean. You want to cite like this for example [Author98], but then you want in the list of references something like 1. [Author98] Title, Autor, Year?

Answer (score 6):

You may want to change to [`BiblaTex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), it is the future since it's much more customizable than [`BibTex`](http://www.bibtex.org/).
You can do what you asked for using this*:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}
```

*I took it from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/biblatex-enumerating-sorted-bibliography-using-authoryear-ibid-style) question. When you put this in the preamble, you will get what you need:

**If** you decide to move to Biblatex, you may want to use [`Biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) as the backend. Finally, these two questions will help you a lot to change. [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex/5095#5095) and [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber).

[image: numbered bibliography]

Comment: I guess I would have to take issue with your claim that one can "easily create" a biblatex style (file) for biblatex. Developing a well crafted and coherent style guide for a bibliography requires careful and methodical work. Moreover, with the help of the `makebst.tex` utility, which is included in most modern TeX distributions, it's not exactly difficult to create a bibtex bibliography style file either.

Comment: Bear in mind that many journal publishers don't use bibLaTeX yet, so this may not be a great option if you plan on submitting your work to a journal.

Comment: @Mico I deleted that part, thanks, I have no experience in such a thing, I never created a style myself. I just read it before moving to biblatex. Maybe someone was trying to sell me something :D

Comment: I also just start using tex. The 2 recommend sources are really helpful. Thank you for sharing that as part of your answer!