# Reverse numbering in biblatex bibliography with different categories

Tags: biblatex, numbering

I have different categories (filters) for entries in a bibliography using
`biblatex` (see below). I would like to add a numbering to the entries. Since the
entries are sorted by year in decreasing order, the numbering (in each category)
should also be decreasing.

Basically, I see two routes to go:

1) The first is to use `style=numeric` and a solution presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21401/biblatex-reverse-numbering-i-e-count-down).
However, in my (not so minimal) example, there appeared two problems. First, the
number does not start over again for each of the categories (instead, it
continues). Second, I obtained weird numbers (up to 400), although I only had a
couple of entries with the same keyword.

2) The second (probably easier) I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/biblatex-enumerating-sorted-bibliography-using-authoryear-ibid-style). This is actually a nice idea (and lets you specify the numbering etc.), but I
couldn't figure out two things: First, how to get decreasing numbering. Second,
if you have > 9 entries, the space reserved for the label is too small and the
10th entry is not vertically aligned with the 9 before. This can probably be
adjusted with `itemindent`, but when I tried, the adjustments did not have an
effect.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear,% numeric,
sorting=ydnt% sort by year (descending), name, title
]{biblatex}

% create dummy .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{mykey1,
    author={I Me},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX questions},
    pages={1--10},
    title={My first LaTeX problem},
    volume={2},
    number={2},
    year={2011},
        keywords={published}}

@article{mykey2,
    author={I Me},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX questions},
    pages={1--10},
    title={My second LaTeX problem},
    volume={1},
    number={1},
    year={2012},
        keywords={submitted}}

@article{mykey3,
    author={I Me},
    journal={Journal of LaTeX questions},
    pages={1--10},
    title={My third LaTeX problem},
    volume={3},
    number={3},
    year={2013},
        keywords={submitted}}
\end{filecontents*}

% bibliography settings
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}% separate bibitems by indentation
\defbibheading{submitted}{\large\sffamily Submitted}% heading
\defbibheading{published}{\large\sffamily Published}% heading
\defbibfilter{submitted}{keyword=submitted}% filter
\defbibfilter{published}{keyword=published}% filter
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}% bibliography data

% % Idea 1) 
% \AtDataInput{%
%   \csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
%     \csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
% \newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
%   \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

% Idea 2)
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}% => adjustments seem to have no effect
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}% => adjustments seem to have no effect
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}


\begin{document}
\section*{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=submitted, filter=submitted]
\noindent\printbibliography[heading=published, filter=published]
\end{document}
```

**Some more information**

1) `bibtex` as backend is used here on purpose (so that `texi2pdf` runs `biblatex` automatically)

2) This problem comes from a CV. The idea is to use `\nocite{*}` (and not specific `\cite{...}`s so that I don't have to care about updating the references).

3) In the CV, I show categories "In preparation", "Submitted", "Published", "Book contributions", "Books". I use the following filtering to get this:

```
\defbibfilter{inpreparation}{type=article and keyword=inpreparation}
\defbibfilter{submitted}{type=article and keyword=submitted}
\defbibfilter{published}{type=article and keyword=published}
\defbibfilter{bookcontrib}{type=incollection and ( keyword=inpreparation or keyword=submitted or keyword=published )}
\defbibfilter{book}{type=book and ( keyword=inpreparation or keyword=submitted or keyword=published )}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [first solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21401/4483) mentioned doesn't work because your bibliography is split by keywords, not by reference sections. The general approach still applies provided that you make the counters keyword-specific.

```
\AtDataInput{%
  \csnumgdef{entrycount:\strfield{keywords}}{%
    \csuse{entrycount:\strfield{keywords}}+1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}    
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\strfield{keywords}}+1-#1\relax}
```

This format has a few limitations:

- It only applies to keyword filtering, not more general filters defined via `\defbibfilter`.
- The item label width corresponds to `\labelnumberwidth`. This length is successively increased to accommodate the largest labelnumber based on all entries in the `bbl` file. So if the keywords filter out many entries, you may find the width too large.

If you don't intend to use the labelnumbers in citations (e.g. entries are accessed only via `\nocite`), then a simple solution to the above limitations is to patch `\printbibligraphy`. The following example demonstrates this approach. It also prints entries in the `authoryear` style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,sorting=ydnt,labelnumber,
  defernumbers]{biblatex}

\defbibfilter{primary}{type=article and keyword=primary}
\defbibfilter{secondary}{keyword=secondary}
\defbibfilter{other}{not type=article and not type=manual and not keyword=secondary}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@printbibliography}
  {\blx@bibliography\blx@tempa}
  {\setcounter{bibitemtotal}{0}%
   \setlength{\labelnumberwidth}{0pt}%
   \begingroup
   \def\do##1{\stepcounter{bibitemtotal}}%
   \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
   \endgroup
   \blx@setlabwidth{\labelnumberwidth}{%
     \csuse{abx@ffd@*@labelnumberwidth}{\arabic{bibitemtotal}}}%
   \blx@bibliography\blx@tempa}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcounter{bibitemtotal}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\value{bibitemtotal}+1-#1\relax}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{glashow,
  author = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  volume = {22},
  date = {1961},
  pages = {579--588},
  keywords = {stdmodel,primary}}
@article{weinberg,
  author = {Weinberg, Steven},
  title = {A Model of Leptons},
  journaltitle = {Phys.~Rev.~Lett.},
  volume = {19},
  date = {1967},
  pages = {1264--1266},
  keywords = {stdmodel,primary}}
@inproceedings{salam,
  author = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  booktitle = {Elementary particle theory},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium},
  location = {Stockholm},
  date = {1968},
  pages = {367--377},
  keywords = {primary,stdmodel}}
@book{augustine,
  author = {Augustine, Robert L.},
  title = {Heterogeneous catalysis for the synthetic chemist},
  publisher = {Marcel Dekker},
  location = {New York},
  date = {1995},
  keywords = {secondary}}
@book{kullback,
  title = {Information Theory and Statistics},
  author = {Kullback, Solomon},
  year = {1959},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  location = {New York}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{oberdiek-bundle.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[filter=primary,title={Primary articles}]
\printbibliography[filter=secondary,title={Secondary works},resetnumbers]
\printbibliography[filter=other,title={Other works},resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Audrey. Unfortunately, it does not compile (Ubuntu 12.10, TeXLive 2012, texi2pdf). 1) Is it crucial to have `biber` as backend? I used `bibtex` (see **Update**), but I obtain output containing `Database file #1: foo-blx.bib
Database file #2: biblatex-examples.bib` ... 2) The whole problem is part of a CV (see the update above). My fear with your solution (although I can't try) is that the numbering is relative to all `\nocite{*}` "entries" and not just counts the entries shown in the bibliography. I definitely wouldn't want having to `\cite{}` all entries by hand.

Comment: Okay, let me try some things... I get back to you ...

Comment: The problem is `biblatex-examples.bib` where `texi2pdf` exits abnormally. For my own `.bib`, compiling works well and the numbers are decreasing. However, they are still not correct, the reason being that my filters are of the form `type=article and keyword=primary`, not just `keyword=primary` (or even `type=incollection and ( keyword=primary or keyword=secondary )`). For example, you don't want to mix books and articles (=> filter different types as well). Because of this subsetting, some of the numbers are missing. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Another problem is the `numeric` style: How does one get the years printed as for the `authoryear` style (right after the authors' names)?

Comment: @MariusHofert So you're filtering by `type` and `keyword`? Anything else? A solution relies on exactly how you're splitting the bibliographies. Without accurate information on this, I can't offer a solution. You should have no problem using BibTeX. You can also use `\nocite{*}`, but again if your bib file is large relative to the number of printed entries `\labelnumberwidth` is going to be too wide. There are ways around this, but I need more details on the filters.

Comment: Hi Audrey. I am filtering by `type` and `keyword` in the two ways I showed in my second-last post. Apart from the numbering, which (due to this filtering) is not correct so far, and the fact that I don't know how to get years printed as in `authoryear` style (but that's rather a detail), everything works. I updated my post to show the exact filters I use in the original example.

Comment: @MariusHofert OK. I think that's enough detail for filtering. `authoryear` style is easy to do. Can `\labelnumberwidth` pose an issue? In other words, does your `bib` file contain many entries that aren't printed?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. My `.bib` file contains many entries (all papers/books I have ever cited), but I grab all that correspond to the filtering (which are mainly my own papers etc.).

Comment: Excellent, Audrey, all problems solved! Thanks! I used `\setlength{\labelwidth}{\widthof{[10]}}` in the redefinition of `bibliography. This guaranteed that different categories (one with < 10, one with >= 10 entries) get correctly vertically aligned.

Comment: @MariusHofert That defeats the purpose of automatically resetting `\labelnumberwidth`. You can omit the relevant code in the patch if you prefer to set the label width manually.

Comment: Hi @Audrey, I am trying to implement this with biblatex 3.6, and the numbers are out of order (i.e. [3], [1], [2]). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Brett you sound like you didn't enable defernumbers.
If you're also printing label prefixes (such as J for journal, C for proceedings etc.) you can just replace the line `{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]\printfield{labelnumber}}}` with `{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\printfield{labelprefix}\printfield{labelnumber}}}`, no need for anything else to calculate widths.

Comment: Can I get hold of the value when having the heading printed, e.g.  `\printbibliography[filter=primary,title={Primary articles (\thelabelnumber)}]` ?